# Call function from code behind in Global.asax

Tags: asp.net, global-asax

How can i access a control or function from asp page (code behind) in Global.asax?

i use below code for background task, this code check for new emails every 60 seconds and i want to update a label that show new email's count in default.aspx

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    AddTask("CheckEmails", 10);
}

private void AddTask(string name, int seconds)
{
    OnCacheRemove = new CacheItemRemovedCallback(CacheItemRemoved);
    HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(name, seconds, null, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(seconds), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
    CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, OnCacheRemove);
 }//addTask

 public void CacheItemRemoved(string k, object v, CacheItemRemovedReason r)
 {
    //Check New Emails and update label from .aspx
    AddTask(k, Convert.ToInt32(v));
 }//CacheItemRemoved
```

Comment: Make it `public static`. It doesn't sound like a good design decision, though.

Comment: from where did you get this value `name` and `second`?

Comment: from Application_Start

Answer (score 0):

why do you to do this. Kindly provide some more information.
Though you can create an object of `Default page` and call it's function. 
But still if that is not related to the page then only it is good to use.

### Edit 1

You don't need it to call from `application start`.
**You can call this function on your page load(which is called after login page).**
You can check for the existing value in the cache with the same key.
If it exist then don't modify the cache
Else Put your values in the cache.

Comment: you should provide some code like what is there in default page (function) and on what event of global page you want to call it.

Comment: how to update Label's text that exist in .aspx from Global now

Answer (score 0):

Create a seperate class for common function, put it in app_code folder, then access this function from Default.aspx and global.asax....

Comment: I can access this class from Global but can't access .aspx from this class,just access class from .aspx.cs and it's not good because i need to update a label's text

Comment: Have you create a namespace in class ?

Comment: I add `namespace NAME` at begining  of class now but can't access it

Comment: Your class ! :) with your namespace .

Comment: Reference this link > http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpide/thread/4b337807-6372-48cd-9d2c-38e05b3dbb98/